# Mobile Website Development

Tags: mobile

Are there any tools for **Mobile Website** (**not** Mobile Application) Development?

For computer websites, CSS grids like Blueprint CSS are used. Is there any thing similar for the mobile version?

There's lot of talk about **HTML5 + CSS3 + Javascript** - a combination thats going to transform Mobile Websites. Not sure how true. Any good tutorials or starting points that you could suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For touch devices [jqtouch](http://jqtouch.com/) is a good solution. There are also commercial ones like [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/06/17/introducing-sencha-touch-html5-framework-for-mobile/).

Comment: 2 questions:
[1] Talking of Mobile Websites, Should 2 Mobile specific Website versions be developed - one for touch based, & one for non-touch based devices?
[2] Are jqtouch & jQuery Mobile different?

Comment: For [1] I would say "yes, if you have the time". You should use the same html but different CSS. Touch screens can give better UX and are usually larger then non-touch.

Comment: For [2], yes they are different. I don't know JQuery Mobile enough to say if it's better, worse, or the same. I only know that it is quite new.

Comment: Thanks Nir. Any mobile website development tools for Non-touch mobile devices that you would highly recommend?

Comment: sorry VDG, don't know about frameworks for non-touch devices, you should read some more on http://mtld.mobi/

Answer (score 0):

Check out a responsive framework like [zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) or [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). If you stick with what the frameworks have, you can have **one** codebase of the site that works in mobile browsers also.